# Kubernetes Cockpit username and password are incorrect

Tags: kubernetes, cockpit

I am working with Kubernetes tutorial and deploying the cluster locally with Vagrant.

After the vagrant machine finishes its loading, I get the following outout:

> ```
> Kubernetes cluster is running.
> The master is running at:
> https://10.245.1.2
> Administer and visualize its resources using Cockpit:
>  https://10.245.1.2:9090
> For more information on Cockpit, visit http://cockpit-project.org
> The user name and password to use is located in /Users/me/.kube/config
> ```

When i go to `https://10.245.1.2:9090` i see the login fedora screen.
I do the following:

> ```
> ./cluster/kubectl.sh config view
> apiVersion: v1
> clusters:
> - cluster:
>     certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
>     server: https://10.245.1.2
>   name: vagrant
> contexts:
> - context:
>   cluster: vagrant
>     user: vagrant
>   name: vagrant
> current-context: vagrant
> kind: Config
> preferences: {}
> users:
> - name: vagrant
>   user:
>     client-certificate-data: REDACTED
>     client-key-data: REDACTED
>     password: 9r5V2B2wn6oeaciX
>     username: admin
> ```

but the username and password are incorrect.

how am i supposed to connect to the cockpit?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The username and password in the kubeconfig file are used to authenticate to the Kubernetes apiserver running in your cluster. The authentication for Cockpit is entirely separate.

According to the [vagrant setup scripts](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/2e89f555c650c01ba577a015fd1b23dbb71707e3/cluster/vagrant/provision-master.sh#L107-L108), you should log into Cockpit as the user `vagrant` with the password `vagrant`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you don't use the right context for *kubectl*.

Try the existing username+password from your config file */Users/me/.kube/config* or set up the context correctly.

See [kubectl config](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config/) for this issue.

Otherwise you could try this Vagrant tutorial: [Kubernetes on CoreOS/Vagrant](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-vagrant-single.html)

Comment: /Users/me/.kube/config presents the same username/password as listed in the question. and i am using the official tutorial from kubernetes website, isn't it good enough?

Comment: I quickly ran the official K8s tutorial on my own machine using _export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=virtualbox; curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash_ - I don`t understand how you went from the official tutorial to the cockpit management console ... The official vagrant build includes **Master, Heapster, KubeDNS, kubernetes-dashboard, Grafana and InfluxDB**.

Comment: Yes, and they all generate the same result with incorrect username and password.